# Lwjgl Compilation Error: Vertex Error. Cant figure out the problem

Tags: java, opengl, glsl, lwjgl, glfw

My problem is my vertex shader and my fragment shader have error but I can't find them.

default.glsl:

```c
#type vertex
#version 330 core
layout (location=0) in vec3 aPos;
layout (location=1) in vec4 aColor;

void main()
{
    fColor = aColor;

    gl_Position = vec4(aPos, 1.0);
}

#type fragment
#version 330 core

in vec4 fColor;

out vec4 color;

void main()
{
    color = fColor;
}
```

compile code:

```java
// Compile and link the shaders

// Compile the vertex shader
vertexID = glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
// Pass the shader source code to the GPU
glShaderSource(vertexID, vertexShaderSource);
glCompileShader(vertexID);

// Check for errors in compilation

if (glGetShaderi(vertexID, GL_COMPILE_STATUS) == GL_FALSE) {
    System.err.println("Failed to compile vertex shader!");
    System.err.println(glGetShaderInfoLog(vertexID));
    //System.exit(-1);
}

// Compile the fragment shader
fragmentID = glCreateShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);
// Pass the shader source code to the GPU
glShaderSource(fragmentID, fragmentShaderSource);
glCompileShader(vertexID);

// Check for errors in compilation
if (glGetShaderi(fragmentID, GL_COMPILE_STATUS) == GL_FALSE) {
    System.err.println("Failed to compile vertex shader!");
    System.err.println(glGetShaderInfoLog(fragmentID));
    //System.exit(-1);
}

// Link shaders and check for errors
shaderProgram = glCreateProgram();
glAttachShader(shaderProgram, vertexID);
glAttachShader(shaderProgram, fragmentID);

glLinkProgram(shaderProgram);

// Check for linking errors
int success = glGetProgrami(shaderProgram, GL_LINK_STATUS);
if (success == GL_FALSE) {
    int len = glGetProgrami(shaderProgram, GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH);
    System.out.println("ERROR: 'defaultShader.glsl'\n\t Linking of shaders failed");
    System.out.println(glGetShaderInfoLog(shaderProgram, len));
    //assert false : "";
}

// Generate VAO, VBO and EBO buffer objects, and send them to the GPU

vaoID = glGenVertexArrays();
glBindVertexArray(vaoID);

// Create a float buffer of vertices
FloatBuffer vertexBuffer = BufferUtils.createFloatBuffer(vertexArray.length);
vertexBuffer.put(vertexArray).flip();

// Create the VBO and upload the vertex buffer
vboID = glGenBuffers();
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vboID);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexBuffer, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

// Create the indices and upload
ByteBuffer buffer;
IntBuffer elementBuffer = BufferUtils.createIntBuffer(elementArray.length);
elementBuffer.put(elementArray).flip();

eboID = glGenBuffers();
glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, eboID);
glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, elementBuffer, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

// Add the vertex attribute pointers
int positionsSize = 3;
int colourSize = 4;
int floatSizeBytes = 4;
int vertexSizeBytes = (positionsSize + colourSize) * floatSizeBytes;
glVertexAttribPointer(0, positionsSize, GL_FLOAT, false, vertexSizeBytes, 0);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);

glVertexAttribPointer(1, colourSize, GL_FLOAT, false, vertexSizeBytes, positionsSize * floatSizeBytes);
glEnable(1);
```

The problem is if I change my compile code from not closing the window when I get an error the square draws perfectly.

but for some reason I get this:

> ```
> Failed to compile vertex shader!
> ```

it can't be a bug with lwjgl I just made another project with it and it worked fine.

I cant figure out what is wrong here.

Comment: Correcting the code in the question makes my answer useless. Don't do that.

Comment: @Rabbid that is the only error I get

Comment: @Rabbid but the way I load the file is very different than how I usually do it

Comment: @Rabbid thanks I'll check my code over again and try loading it another way

Comment: What is the output from `glGetShaderInfoLog(vertexID)`? Try printing the `vertexShaderSource` before compiling the shader code.

Comment: when I print it the fragment shader prints but the vertex shader does not. @Rabbid76

Comment: Now you know that there is a bug is in the part of the code that is reading the file. –

Comment: @Rabbid76 I printed it before I compiled and it printined it and the output of glGetShaderInfoLog() is noting what I put in the post is all I get

Answer (score 2):

There is an error in the vertex shader. The declaration of the output variable `fColor` is  missing:

```c
layout (location=0) in vec3 aPos;
layout (location=1) in vec4 aColor;

out vec4 fColor;                     // <--- this is missing 

void main()
{
    fColor = aColor;

    gl_Position = vec4(aPos, 1.0);
}
```

Comment: @ImmanuelC There is no further error in the shader code.